# Unknown signal 6 on Coursera grader, working fine on local system

Tags: c++, data-structures

The task is to input a series of numbers representing the parent node of the corresponding 0 based indexed nodes (if the number is -1 then it is the root of the tree) and output the height of the tree. The wrote the following code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


void ranking( int  i, int   a, vector <int>  &parent, vector <int> &rank)
{
    if(rank[i] + 1 > rank[a])
    {
        rank[a] = rank[i] + 1;

        if(parent[a]!= -1)
        {
            ranking(a, parent[a], parent, rank);
        }
        
    }

}

 int  main()
{
     int  n;
    cin >> n;
    int  a;

    vector <int>   parent(n);
    vector <int>   rank(n, 0);

    for ( int  i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            cin>> parent[i];
            if(parent[i] < 0)
                a=i;
        }

    for ( int  i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        ranking(i, parent[i], parent, rank);
    }

    cout << rank[a] + 1<< endl;

    

    return 0;
}
```

The code is running properly on my system but showing unknown signal 6 on Coursera grader. Please help me understand what could be wrong here, I don't have much idea about how programs handles memory